# Why variables are not defined in the directive controller?

Tags: angularjs

I can not understand why the variable is undefined in the directive controller:

```js
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app', [])
    .directive('myExample', myExample, ['$scope']);

function myExample() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<span>{{vm.date}}</span>',
        scope: {},
        controller: ExampleController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: {
            date: '@'
        }
    };

    return directive;
}

function ExampleController($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    // I need here some code with vm.date
    // BUT vm.date is undefined
    // Why?
    console.log('Ctrl: %s', vm.date);

    $scope.$watch('vm.date', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        // vm.date is 777
        console.log('Ctrl: %s | %s', oldValue, newValue);
  });
}
```

```html
<body ng-app="app">
  <my-example date="777"></my-example>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Why vm.date is not defined? How to do so that it was defined?

I tried to use the same method with `link`. No problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the binding is not there at the moment when `ExampleController` is constructed. Since v1.6 you need to use `$onInit`:

```
function ExampleController($scope) {
  var vm = this;

  this.$onInit = function() {
    console.log('Ctrl: %s', vm.date);  
  }
}
```

And remove `$scope`, you don't need it at all (avoid it).

Alternatively, you can reenable old binding behavior with `preAssignBindingsEnabled` setting of `$compileProvider`:

```
.config(function($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);
});
```

but better switch to `$onInit` option as this is how it will be from now on (and how it is in Angular 2).

Comment: I use `$scope` for tests. Thank you for the help! It works with `$onInit`. I think `vm.$onInit` is more nice.